# how backwards compatible are new iOS SDK features

Tags: ios

If the SDK adds new features, will these things work on the older devices?  If the API gets new methods, does the compiler handle these new methods to get to some internal native code, or will the new features added not be able to be used on devices not running the new OS?

Answer (score 5):

When Apple add new SDK features, they almost always rely on new frameworks or runtime features that are simultaneously added to the OS and unavailable on earlier iterations. There are rare exceptions, but they're always to do with an SDK feature being added to the compiler. For example, per the disclosed information on automatic reference counting in the iOS 5 SDK it seems reasonable to assume you'll be able to build iOS 4 applications with all ARC features except self-zeroing weak pointers because that requires some runtime support. Though we won't know for certain until the tools as Apple intends to supply them come out of NDA.

Apple instead expect you to use the dynamic nature of the Objective-C runtime to use new features only as and when they are available and to set your base deployment target to the lowest supported version of the OS on which your application functions to a reasonable extent.

For example:

```
if(![someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(relevantNewMethod)])
{
    // this version of the OS doesn't actually have relevantNewMethod
    // so we'll do something else instead; attempting to use it will
    // raise an exception on this device
}
```

Or:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"ShinyNewiOSClass"))
{
    // ShinyNewiOSClass is implemented on this version of the OS, so
    // we can use it. Otherwise we'd better find something else to do
    // instead...
}
```

`NSClassFromString` returns either the `Class` instance or `nil` if no class with that name exists, so you can instead take the result of NSClassFromString and do the customary alloc init on it if you prefer.

A classic example would be showing an 'email' button only if `MFMailComposer` is available (if you had wanted to support iOS 2 while using iOS 3 methods where available).

For entirely new frameworks standard practice is to weak link (which means your program would like them to be loaded but the OS shouldn't raise an exception if they don't exist) and then to use the same reflective features to check if the relevant classes are available at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, an SDK update generally coincides with an OS update. Therefore, any features added to the SDK will only be available in OS versions that support that SDK.

I'll give an Android-based example, but I believe the process behind it is the same for iOS:

> Android 2.1 == SDK v7 (API level 7)
>
> Android 2.2 == SDK v8 (API level 8)

Any features available starting in SDK v8 will not be available to phones running Android 2.1 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

An SDK goes with a particular iOS version.  The SDK for iOS 5.0 gives apps compiled with it an interface to the 5.0 features (as well as to all older features or APIs).  Those features that are new in 5.0 can only be used on devices that have 5.0 installed.  The app can detect whether it is running on a device that has the feature and avoid using the feature if the device does not have the iOS version that supports the feature.  If an app attempts to use a 4.0 feature (for example) while it is running on a device that has iOS 3.1.3 installed the app will get an exception and crash.

Some devices, like the original iPhone, cannot load the latest iOS versions.  The original iPhone is stuck at 3.1.3.  The iPhone 3G gets 4.X but it some features are disabled (like multitasking).  This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) has a useful what the maximum iOS version the various devices can run.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, to maintain backwards compatibility, new features added to SDKs are "opt in" and would require you to release a new version of your application taking advantage of them. There is always an exception to the rule, but this is usually the case.

Comment: This is a true statement, but it appears he was asking if the OS would support the new features automatically rather than if an application could use the new features automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I originally read the question wrong...

If the question is... if I program for an iOS5 feature, will that feature be supported on iOS 4?

Then the answer is... no.

Unless you do something like the defensive measures mentioned by Tommy, your application will either not compile at all, or will crash when those features are accessed.